# Append a value to an existing column in a dataframe after conditions

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I want to append new values to an existing column with values in a dataframe.

Example: This is the initial dataframe

```
name    gender   age  
harry     M      10    
martha    F      11
```

After checking conditions the data frame expands and adds a new column with values:

```
name    gender   age   remarks
harry     M      10    is_boy 
martha    F      11    is_girl
```

and again the process continues

This is the Final dataframe

```
name    gender   age   remarks
harry     M      10    is_boy | iowa | 2008
martha    F      11    is_girl| florida | 2007
```

This is a bit tricky for me as I have spend a lot of time behind this.

Would like to know how the code will look like.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `s` the new Series at each loop, simply add the new data :

```
for s in function_generating_new_data():
    # only if type is unsure
    s = s.astype(str)
    if 'remarks' in df:
        # add data
        df['remarks'] += ' | '+s
    else:
        df['remarks'] = s
```

Answer (score 0):

For new column "remarks" there are multiple ways:

**list comprehension:**

```
df["remarks"] = ["is_boy" if gender =="M" else "is_girl" for gender in df['gender']]
```

**np.where:**

```
df["remarks"] = np.where(df["gender"]=="M","is_boy","is_girl")
```

You can see other methods from [this link](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-create-column-based-on-condition/).

I assume the information "state | year" is in a list.

***The simplest way:***

```
additional_info = ["iowa | 2008","florida | 2007"]
df["remarks"] = df["remarks"] + " | " + additional_info
```